# Pass qml function to c++ class to connect

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ class that is exposed to QML. The C++ class contains a function that is prefixed with `Q_INVOKABLE` so it can be called from QML context. Currently, the function expects a `QObject` and `const char *` that represents a slot. The function then connects up that slot to an internal C++ signal. Problem is, I don't see any way for QML to trigger this function from it's side because QML functions don't translate to the slot data qt expects. Is there a way to formulate what I am expecting between QML and C++?

Comment: If the final purpose of such code is to connect the C++ signal to the (eventual) QML slot, you can do that via the [`Connections` element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html): the `target` could be the C++ object emitting the signal whereas the (QML) "slot" function can be called in the signal handler which assumes the name `on[C++_SIGNAL_NAME_HERE]`. [See here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) for an example.

Comment: I didn't think about setting it up this way, but this will work. Thanks!