# How to pass a callback function from qml to C++?

Tags: c++, qml

Related but different (I think): [Pass qml function to c++ class to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874588/pass-qml-function-to-c-class-to-connect)

I want to pass a callback function from qml into C++. That is, I want something like

```
// qml
myCPPObject.setCallback(function(result) { log("Got result", result) })
```

and on the C++ side, I'd want something like

```
// C++
void MyCPPObject::setCallback(std::function<void(QVariant)> cb) { m_cb = cb; }
```

Is there a way to do this? I'd be OK if it were a named function in qml or if it were something other than `std::function` on the C++ side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible with `QJSValue`, [see Qt Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html) and this example:

```
class myCppObject : QObject
{
    void setCallback(QJSValue func)
    {
        callback_ = func;
    }

    void whenCalled()
    {
        if(callback_.isCallable())
        {
            QJSValueList args;
            //args.append(...)
            callback_.call(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Only minor downside being that the arguments are not named, so you have to take care to define and adhere the interface on both sides.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. The lack of static safety is sadly par for the course with qml, of course.  Our convention has been to write primarily for C++ and then prefix `qml_` on function names with loose typing that we only ever want to call from qml, so I'd write this as `void setCallback(std::function<void(int result)> cb) { m_callback = std::move(cb); } void qml_setCallback(QJSValue func) { if (callback_.isCallable()) { setCallback([cb=std::move(callback_)](int result) { cb.call(QJSValueList{result}); }); } void whenCalled() const { if (m_callback) { m_callback(m_result); } }`